# Be $\mathbb{L}$ a subfield of $\mathbb{K}$, show $0 \in \mathbb{L}$ and $1 \in \mathbb{L}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> The Definition of **subfield** used in this exercise (excuse my translation skills):
>
> Be $(\mathbb{K},+,\cdot,0,1)$ a field. $\mathbb{L} \subseteq \mathbb{K}$, then $\mathbb{L}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{K}$, if it has at least 2 elements and if the following is true:
>
> If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{L}$ and $z \ne 0$, then $\frac{x-y}{z} \in \mathbb{L}$

Now $\mathbb{L}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{K}$. I have to proof the following:

$0 \in \mathbb{L}$ and $1 \in \mathbb{L}$

Now **my approach** would be to set (x,y,z) so that the function produces $0$ and $1$.
The function goes as defined above, im just rewriting it to exclude missunderstandings:

$f: \mathbb{L} \rightarrow \mathbb{L}, (x,y,z)\mapsto \frac{x-y}{z}, z \ne 0$

*Trying to get $0$:* $f(x,x,z) = \frac{x-x}{z} = \frac{0}{z} = 0$

*Trying to get $1$:* $f(z,0,z) = \frac{z-0}{z} = \frac{z}{z} = 1$

Im not sure if $\frac{x-y}{z}$ implies, that the additive inverse of x is -x and whether $z^{-1}$ is the multiplicative invserse of z. Is it logical to assume this or is there another way around to get $0$ and $1$ with this definition?

**Edit:** Working on a correct solution (all edits below):

1) *Trying to prove $0 \in \mathbb{L}$*:

We know there are at least 2 Elements in $\mathbb{L}$, one of them being $\ne 0$, lets call it $b$ and the other one a(arbitrary).

$f(a,a,b) = \frac{a-a}{b} = \frac{0}{b} = 0$

Now, because we only have 2 Elements with $b \ne 0$, there must exist an element with the value $0$, let a be this element.

2) *Trying to prove $1 \in \mathbb{L}$*:

$f(b,a,b) = \frac{b-a}{b} = \frac{b-0}{b} = \frac{b}{b} = 1$

Now $a = 0$, so if there are only 2 elements, $b = 1$

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

You're doing well, but in your first example, what are $x$ and $z$? You might say "They could be anything!", but that's not quite true: $z$ needs to be invertible, hence cannot be zero. And to be explicit, you should take as $z$ something you *know* is not zero -- like "1", for instance. (You have an axiom that says $1 \ne 0$, right?)

Now you also need a value for $x$, and in that case, anything will work, but it's clearer if you make it explicit, like saying "Take $x = 0$, or simply say

"Apply the hypothesis to $x = y = 0$ and $z = 1$ to get that $0/1 = 0 \in L$."

Now can you do the same thing for the other claim?

Comment: We don't have the $1 \ne 0$ axiom eplicitly, but it is okey for us to assume thats what is meant here, just like $x-x = 0$, else this exercise would be little bit over the top for my course

Comment: Without that axiom, the set $\{0\}$ would form a field (with $1$ being the same as $0$).

Comment: Yes I actually found it in "our" definition of a Field

Comment: I updated my attempt, I hope I implemented your suggestion of how to approach this

Comment: Sure, that's OK. But the last sentence of each part of your proof is unnecessary: you know that $f(a,a,b) \in L$, so $0 \in L$. And you know that $f(b,0,b) \in L$, so $1 \in L$. And now you've proved what you need to prove.